# regex to not allow decimal fractions without leading zero

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, ecmascript-6, angular9

The regex `(^-?[1-9]*?0?(\.\d+)?$)|(^\d+\.$)` allow user to type the following decimal or integer values

```
0.500
3
0
0.0
30
500000
4000.22
0.
-0.500
-3
```

and not allow

```
03.3, 00, 02, 00.0
```

but the above regex also allows `.3`, `.4`

Is there a way of not to allow `.3` or `.44` Thanks

My attempt:
`(^-?[1-9]*?0+?(\.\d+)?$)|(^\d+\.$)` which doesn't seem to work

Comment: Why are you using regex for numerical range check?

Comment: I am using formcontrol for input box, and would like to show validation error when it doesn't match the above regex

Comment: Are you specifically trying to exclude the exact values 0.3, 0.4, and 0.44, or are you trying to require that the user always provide a leading 0 for fractional values less than 1? Which variant of regular expressions are you using? What rules would apply to negative numbers?

Comment: i would like to include 0.3 but not allow user to type .3 without 0 in front

Comment: is .3 a proper value? do you think user should type a leading 0 before the dot?

Comment: The pattern allows .3 and .44 because all on the left of the alternation is optional, so `(?:\.\d+)` will match those value.

Comment: can you please help provide input for the regex? I have tried remove it but it also excludes 3 and 0

Comment: Perhaps like this `^\d+\.?\d*$`  https://regex101.com/r/GAD0Ay/1

Comment: yes 10. is valid because I would like to show the error only when user typing.

Comment: Using the `|` sign, you should split your regex into two cases. One in which there is a decimal fraction and the other in which there isn't. Btw, I can't see why you would not allow such input. Why would you care?

Comment: @Thefourthbird the regex works but would like to exclude 00, 00.5  too  and include negative values

Comment: Like this? `^-?(?!00)\d+\.?\d*$` https://regex101.com/r/C75XKo/1

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird but would also like to exclude 03, -03, -01., 0004

Comment: This does not match all those values `^(?!-?0\d)\d+\.?\d*$` https://regex101.com/r/laqXlA/1

Comment: `^-?(?!0\d)\d+\.?\d*$` may work

Comment: Thanks @thefourthbird ^-?(?!-?0\d)\d+\.?\d*$ works for both positive and negative values, which is what I am looking for

Comment: @anubhava I made a typo, but this should be it `^-?(?!0\d)\d+\.?\d*$` You can post it if you want.

Comment: It was just a minor correction @Thefourthbird. It was your regex solution after all. You should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could match an optional `-` and then assert using a negative lookahead that the pattern does not start with a zero followed by a digit.

Thanks to @[anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) for the correction to make the final pattern.

```
^-?(?!0\d)\d+\.?\d*$
```

**The pattern in parts**

- `^` Start of string
- `-?` Match optional hyphen
- `(?!0\d)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly to the right is not 0 and a digit
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `\.?\d*` Match optional `.` and 0+ digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jd2Z6y/1)